# Case Statement (Reportbuilder)

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have the following case statement, the AppointmentDate isn’t always populated and therefore require to pull from other date fields - looking to have one appointment date (populated from many fields)
When running this statement, doesn’t return full results.

,Case=Appointment
When AppointmentDate Is Null Then ChaseDate
When ChaseDate Is Null Then DueDate
Else AppointmentDate
End

Any thoughts on where I’ve went wrong?

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't stated if this is supposed to be an expression in SSRS or this is part of your dataset query.

Assuming SQL Server here...

If this is part of your dataset query then you can do something like

```
SELECT 
    FieldA, FieldB,
    myAppointmentDate = COALESCE(AppointmentDate, ChaseDate, DueDate)
FROM myTable
```

`COALESCE` will return the first non-null value

If you are trying to do this in an SSRS expression then you need to use the `SWITCH()` statement.

```
=SWITCH(
        Fields!AppointmentDate.Value <> Nothing, Fields!AppointmentDate.Value,
        Fields!ChaseDate.Value <> Nothing, Fields!ChaseDate.Value,
        Fields!DueDate.Value <> Nothing, Fields!DueDate.Value,
        True, Fields!AppointmentDate.Value
       )
```

This will return the first expression that is `true`, if non of the first three exression return true, the final `True` acts like an else (which in your case would return `Nothing` anyway)

Comment: Sorry, part of the dataset query

Comment: OK so just the COALESCE exmaple above. The order of the columns is important though, COALESCE will return the FIRST non-null value.